# Website render in IE 10 and lower

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I've created a website using HTML5. The website renders perfectly fine on Chrome/Firefox and IE 11.

I've accessed the website through IE10 and lower, and the website doesn't show properly at all.

This is how it should look like:

[image]

This is how it actually looks like in IE10 and lower:

[image]

In order to try and add more support to HTML5, I got these lines of code in my header:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE10"> 
<!--[if IE]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

This is the website online if you want to look for something in it:

http://www.domanage.co.il

Comment: Have you used flexbox for layout?

Comment: @Pavlo I'm not sure what it means? The main Wrapper is positioned Relative, the HEADER is fixed, the website remains 1024px wide and doesn't change. I've just started using HTML5 instead of `divs` for everything. So I guess I'm not using flexbox?

Comment: This was a first guess. Anyway, you should localise the problem yourself, IE has developer tools too.

Comment: Make sure your JS is valid.

Comment: @bagonyi my JS is valid I guess. There are no errors returned from any file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nav element and its child ul both have a height of zero pixels. If you set a value they show up. I did not spend the time to figure out where the zero pixels is coming from. Should be a good starting point for you to debug.

Comment: It seems like it's helping a bit but it still doesn't fix the issue. What tool are you using to view it in IE 10 and lower? I'm using some website that gives me a screenshot of the webpage

Comment: If you are going to develop for IE, you should have a VM running IE.

Comment: VM? Can you post me a link please?